# jQuery selector stored in variable: How to Select specific elements by attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that I get an element(s) by attribute via, e.g.

```
$('.js_aBunchOfElements span[data-stuff="special"]');
```

Yet once I store the selector in a variable:

```
var bunch = $('.js_aBunchOfElements span');
```

I am confused how to search within `bunch` for my elements with the attribute `data-stuff="special"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bunch.filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-stuff") == "special";
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`bunch.filter('[data-stuff=special]')` should do it.